# Homestead Laravel Paradox?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I try to create a clean project with Laravel and Homestead, so that if somebody download my project, only a vagrant up is necessary... look like a Paradox or maybe I do something wrong.

- I create a new laravel project dir
- I run `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` to install homestead.
- I get requirements errors because the composer.json was already created from laravel, and it needs the requirements from the VM
- I could do a `composer install` inside the homestead VM
- But the homestead VM doen't exist already because I can't install homestead

To make homestead works but not the right workflow:

- I did a `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` outside the laravel dir and I copied the homestead files inside the laravel project dir
- `vagrant up` from the laravel dir
- `composer install` in the VM （this remove all the homestead files because homestead isn't in the composer.json）

This looks wrong, which would be the right way to add homestead to a laravel project?

Comment: Concept is wrong. You should create homestead virtual environment as anyone else. Then, inside your virtual system OS you would create Laravel project. Then you would want just to share your Laravel project's composer.json/composer.lock file(s). But best way would be to use git/github/bitbucket for sharing project.

Comment: I refer to the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#per-project-installation. If I understand, you say that I have to install laravel in one dir and homestead in an other dir and commit the two dirs as a whole project. (I have to adjust the path in Homestead.yml to the laravel publich dir). Yes I think this would works, and also this would add my homestead configs to my repo. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't create new laravel project in first place. Just `require laravel/homestead`.

Comment: Homestead has nothing with Laravel application in a way. You can install homestead and never use Laravel framework but use Zend or Symfony for making web apps/sites instead. Your goal should be installation of homestead with no look back to `laravel/laravel` in first place.

Comment: Yes, is true. But if I give my laravel Project to the future me or another developer, I want to do little steps as possible to start the project again. That's why I want to have the right homestead config inside my repo. See tools like Trellis for Wordpress or Docker for many more. :)

Comment: Ok. I just read again your question and checked docs again. Never used it per project. I'd thought that every dev should have installed homestead box on their machine. We all need to update machine's packages and for project (sharing) there are tools like composer and git.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out.
You can put the homestead folder and the laravel folder in the same project, like:

```
--project_folder
   |--homestead
   |--laravel
```

And change the path in Homestead.yml to the laravel dir

Then to take the project running:

- do a `compose install` in homestead
- `vagrant up`
- in the VM `compose install` to prepare the laravel app